# Помогите решить баг, не могу понять что не так

Tags: javascript, ajax

Всем привет, есть баг, но не могу понять из-за чего все так работает, сейчас расскажу.

Вот код есть блок  `<div id="coml">` в нем есть кнопка `<div id="intro" class="intro"></div>` по нажатию он обновляет все что `<div id="coml">`, проблема в том что когда первый раз загружаешь страницу то по нажатию на  `<div id="reviews" class="like">` функция(2) работает, но как только проиходит нажатие на `<div id="intro" class="intro">` и блок `<div id="coml">` обновляется, то уже `<div id="reviews" class="like">` не работает, это очень странно, ведь по сути ничего не меняется, просто после обновления `<div id="coml">` все что в нем `<div id="intro" class="intro"></div><div id="reviews" class="like"></div>`  берется из `review_vb.php`, Помогите понять что не так..

```
<div id="coml">
    <div id="intro" class="intro"></div>
    <div id="reviews" class="like"></div>
</div>

$('.intro').click(function(){   
        function show(url, selector){
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",                   
                url: url,
                data: "id="+id,                     
                cache: false,  
                success: function(html){  
                    $(selector).html(html);
                }  
            });  
        }
        show('review_vb.php', '#coml');          
    });

$('.like').click(function(){         
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "likereviews.php",
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){  
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, у вас функции статически привязаны к объектам существующим на момент загрузки страницы и когда появляются новые объекты ваш код не работает потому что он о них не знает.

Попробуйте так:

```
$(document).on('click', '.like', function() {
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "likereviews.php",
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){  
        }
    });
});


$(document).on('click', '.intro', function() {
function show(url, selector){
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",                   
                url: url,
                data: "id="+id,                     
                cache: false,  
                success: function(html){  
                    $(selector).html(html);
                }  
            });  
        }
        show('review_vb.php', '#coml');
});
```

Удачи!

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ, все работает